Error 'Server Disconnected' when using SSH Proxy Tunnel with aiohttp in Python
I'm trying to make requests to an endpoint using a Python script that connects to an SSH proxy tunnel. I set up the SSH tunnel using the following command:
sshpass -p "<my_pass>" ssh -D 8090 my_user@my_server.com

Once the tunnel is established, I'm able to execute commands inside the server. I use this proxy to make HTTP requests through a python script. However, when using async functions in combination with aiohttp, I get the error: Server disconnected
This only happens when I make the requests asynchronously. The issue doesn't occur when I try to make requests without the proxy or with synchronous requests.
Here’s the relevant part of my code that uses aiohttp:
    async def _resilient_request(
        self, url: str, headers: Dict[str, str]
    ) -> Dict[str, Any]:

        proxy = "socks5h://localhost:8090"

        for attempt in range(8):
            try:
                timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=30)
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
                    timeout=timeout, json_serialize=ujson.dumps,
                ) as session:
                    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, ssl=False, proxy=proxy) as resp:
                        resp.raise_for_status()
                        data = await resp.json()
                        return data
            except (
                aiohttp.ClientError,
                aiohttp.ClientResponseError,
                asyncio.TimeoutError,
                aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError,
                aiohttp.ClientConnectorError,
                RuntimeError,
            ) as err:
                if attempt < 3:
                    await asyncio.sleep(attempt + 1)
                    print(
                        f"Resilient request failed. Retrying attempt {attempt + 1}"
                    )
                    print(f"Error: {err}")
                    continue
                else:
                    raise err

What I tried:
I set up an SSH proxy tunnel using the command sshpass -p "<my_pass>" ssh -D 8090 my_user@my_server.com and used aiohttp to make asynchronous requests through this tunnel to an endpoint that requires a proxy.
What I expected to happen:
I expected the asynchronous requests to succeed and return the response from the endpoint, as the proxy tunnel was set up correctly.
What actually happened:
Instead of getting a valid response, I encountered the error Server disconnected when making requests using aiohttp in an asynchronous context. The tunnel works fine for regular, synchronous requests but fails when async is used.

The actual exception/traceback could be helpful.

I have a feeling socks5 isn't supported though, so that might be your issue.
